# com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity vulnerable to Intent Redirection on GooglePlay

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have just got rejection of my app update with the message below.

```
Your app(s) are vulnerable to Intent Redirection.

com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity->onCreate
```

i am using a facebook login in the app and it uses activity as below defined. Simple solution could be to set `exported="false"` but even my build is not working I get a build error " error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1."
I am using xamarin. I am not sure if that is related to it but i guess not.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" android:exported="true" />
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

If i understand correctly, `exported=false` also not a good solution i need data from another app. In this case if user has facebook app installed and login details should be delivered from the facebook app, `exported=false` makes the activity private and cannot receive the data.
So what could be the possible solution here?

Comment: `I get a build error " error MSB6006: "java.exe" exited with code 1."`  How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a duplicate, the first line is not necessary.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity" android:exported="true" />
```

Only use the rest and the sign in works.

Comment: this should be comment and it is not duplicate one of them CustomTabMainActivity, other is CustomTabActivity

Comment: Well the vulnerability is in the first one, what are you using this for?

Comment: i am not entirely sure but i was getting error as activity not found and as stated here, i have just added into manifest. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49529383/android-facebook-sdk-4-31-0-activitynotfoundexception-in-customtabloginmetho

Anyway even it is not the problem. even if you remove it, error remains.

Comment: @Emil you are sure the the error is still "com.facebook.CustomTabMainActivity->onCreate" when you remove the whole line and only leave the other CustomTabActivity?

Comment: yes i already did. I have found the reason was caused my manifest merger.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem with diagnostic build. I have Android library in the project which has also Manifest file. Indeed my Manifest in the Android library project didnt have anything within the application tags as shown below.

```
<application />
```

But somehow setting goes double with once true and other with false. Not sure why but within the logs I have found out that was message like "at the line xx `android:exported="false"` and other line yy `android:exported="true"` use `tools:replace`.
This seems to be caused  by Manifest merger and simply setting as below solved the error and now it builds fine and works as well.

```
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity" 
tools:replace="android:exported" android:exported="false">
```

I hope that it helps in case anyone come across with the same issue